# Delete newline at end of for loop -- python 2.x

Tags: python, for-loop, printing, newline, python-2.x

I have been doing exercises on codeabbey.com to brush the rust off, and I keep running into this small, but still frustrating problem. I want my programs to spit out one line of n items of output *and then* a newline for any n lines of given input, but my programs all spit out one line of (n-1) items, a newline, and then the last item.

Here is an example in which I am given first a number of pairs to be processed, then the pairs themselves, and I am tasked with finding the minimum (Please forgive my lazy use of pre-existing functions):

```
quanta = int(raw_input())
print "\n"

for i in xrange(quanta):
    a = raw_input().split()
    a = map(int, a)
    print min(a),
```

and this input copy-pasted into the command line:

```
3
5 3
2 8
100 15
```

I expect this output:

```
3 2 15
```

but instead I am getting *this* output:

```
3 2
15
```

My question then is **how do I get rid of that trailing newline?**

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Running your code, pasting the input, I get the expected output. There is no extra newline in the output your script produces.

Comment: Could it be a problem with my terminal? I am just using the standard mac os terminal.

Comment: I tested this on a standard Mac OS X terminal myself.

Comment: Do you think it has something to do with my enter key? I tried it in an online compiler and did not experience the same problem. When I copy-paste the input, Terminal will process my code, spit out the answer on one line for n-1 terms, but will not finish (i.e. print the last output) until I hit the enter button.

Comment: Do you have a newline included after the last line of your input? I suspect it is just waiting for more input.

Comment: I do not have the newline unfortunately, but, following the advice of the answer below, I fixed the problem. Bedankt voor de hulp!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce. With this in the copy buffer:

```
3
5 3
2 8
100 15
```

when running the script and pasting this *without trailing newline* the script stays at `a = raw_input().split()` of the third input line, but already outputted the `min` of the two lines above (`3` and `2`), so when you hit newline then `raw_input` enters the newline and the last `min` (`15`) is printed.

One solution is to only print at the end:

```
quanta = int(raw_input())
print "\n"

res = []
for i in xrange(quanta):
    a = raw_input().split()
    a = map(int, a)
    res.append(min(a))

print(" ".join(str(i) for i in res))
```

The other is to also include the trailing newline in the copy-buffer (on `MacOs` you need to drag down the mouse a bit under the line to get the trailing newline selected)

Comment: Thanks for your help! This fixed the problem even in Terminal.

Comment: @ColeWhetstone glad it did the trick, can you accept the answer then?